# Status says Draft in Prod

Tags: android, deployment, google-play

I have completed all steps for making Android app (Google Developer Console). Everything is saved and my App Status says  "**Draft in Prod**"

What is the next step to see the actual version in the Google Play Store?

Answer (score 18):

You have to press the button "publish now" in the upper left corner.

It could be placed better, that's right

Comment: yeah must be better, really big ux  problem :)

Comment: am unable to see the submit update in desabled.increase roll out to 20% showing how to publish new version to store please help

Answer (score 9):

if all steps for publishing were completed on the upper right corner in the Google Developers Console under APK's tab should be a button to publish the app to the Google Play. Otherwise the same button will give you the option to view the reasons why it still can't be published.

Usually people (including me) forget to check 2 checkboxes at the end of Pricing & Distribution page (Content guidelines and US export laws) which are obligatory.

Comment: Those two checkboxes! Hit the nail on the head there for my situation, and saved me a lot of searching, while having to publish an app alone for the first time one evening when everyone else had gone. Thanks!

Comment: In my case I was not aware of Content Guidelines check and US Export laws check. Thanks man for such description.

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert all grey 'right mark' to green 'right mark' for this you need to fill all mandatory field.

all the mandatory fields are inside the menu with grey/green 'right mark'